# Is there a way to monitor /dev/random?

Tags: linux, redhat, jdbc, random-number-generator

We're investigating some JDBC issues, and one of the possible problems is /dev/random being exhausted. The workaround is to switch the JVM to using /dev/urandom, but I wan't to try and determine whether or not the /dev/random is being exhausted.

Is there a way to check if the entropy pool is being exhausted? I've gone hunting for nagios plugins and general bash commands, but I've turned up nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure!  Ask `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

Comment: But... every time I run that I lose entropy!

Comment: @Andrew: There's no reason why you should.

Comment: @David. Entropy does reduce as you run cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail, but only to a point, it will then level out and hover at around the same level

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, cheers.

Comment: I don't know whether this answer ever was correct, but it [does not seem to be for today's kernels](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/127498/165862). `entropy_avail` only measures the size of the input pool, *not* how many bits can be read from `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 2):

as read someplace else... each new process get entropy from /dev/random

a simple way to avoid stealing the pool is a program, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

while True:
    with open('/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read().rstrip())
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: more easy:
watch cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

Comment: @DavidMuñoz Wouldn’t that create a `cat` process every interval? As mentioned in the answer, *each new process gets entropy from `/dev/random`*.